# jQuery Validate plugin, if statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this validate function:

```
var validator =$('#form1').validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        usu_login: { required: true },
        usu_email: { required: true },
        usu_nombre1: { required: true },
        usu_apellido1: { required: true },
        usu_fecha_nac: { required: true },
        usu_cedula: { required: true },
        usu_telefono1: { required: true },
        usu_password: { 
            required: function() { return focusout == true; }
        },
        usu_password2: {
            required: function() { return focusout == true; }
        },
        usu_password3: {
            required: function() { return focusout == true; },
            equalTo: "#usu_password2"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to apply the same `if` statement in the `equalTo` function so this can work as I want to, but I don't know how to do that.

Dows anyone know how? Thanks

Comment: `required: function() { return focusout == true; }` this acts as an if in the validate plugin @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `equalTo` can only take a string selector.

Comment: =( so im screwed, well thanks anyway! @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So you want `equalTo` to be applied if `focusout` is `true`, and otherwise the `equalTo` should be ignored?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want, but i don't know how to do it like in the required rule. @Yogu

Comment: @MarianaHernandez not really, you could add the `equalTo` logic to the required function, if `focusout` is `true`

Comment: how would i do that? i tried this `usu_password3: {
  required: function() { return focusout == true; equalTo: "#usu_password2";}
 }`but it didn't work @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `depends` property of the rule!!!

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var focusout;
    $('#state').change(function(){
        focusout = this.checked;
    }).change();

    var validator = $('#myform').validate({
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            usu_login: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_email: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_nombre1: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_apellido1: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_fecha_nac: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_cedula: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_telefono1: {
                required: true
            },
            usu_password: {
                required: function () {
                    return focusout == true;
                }
            },
            usu_password2: {
                required: function () {
                    return focusout == true;
                }
            },
            usu_password3: {
                required: function () {
                    return focusout == true;
                },
                equalTo: {
                    depends: function(){
                        return focusout == true;
                    },
                    param: "#usu_password2"
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {}
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dp96P/)

Comment: can i ask you a question? how would i do the same with the minlenght validation? with the depend fuction too? thanks @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var rules = {
    usu_login: { required: true },
    usu_email: { required: true },
    usu_nombre1: { required: true },
    usu_apellido1: { required: true },
    usu_fecha_nac: { required: true },
    usu_cedula: { required: true },
    usu_telefono1: { required: true },
    usu_password: { 
        required: function() { return focusout == true; }
    },
    usu_password2: {
        required: function() { return focusout == true; }
    },
    usu_password3: {
        required: function() { return focusout == true; },
        equalTo: "#usu_password2"
    }
}

if (!focusout) {
    for (key in rules) {
        delete rules[key].equalTo;
    }
}

var validator = $('#form1').validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: rules
});
```

The loop iterates over all rules and removes the `equalTo` constraint if it should be ignored.

However, you have to recreate the `validator` object every time you change `focusout`.

Comment: I tried it, thank you, but it doesn't work, because that field usu_password3 is inside a modal, and even if its equealTo NULL, its expecting the input to appear and it hasnt appeared yet becase its inside the modal.

Comment: I changed it to `delete`, which gets rid of the `equalTo` property entirely, as if it was never present. BUt Aurun's answer is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you have to add your own method to validator

```
$.validator.addMethod("mehod", function(value, element) 
{
valid=false;
if(condition==true)//place your  condition
{
valid=true;
}
else
{
valid=false;
}
return this.optional(element) || valid;
},"Your own error message");
```

and place it where you want to validate

like this:

```
rules: {
usu_login: { required: true,method: true },//here you are using your method
usu_email: { required: true }
/*other rule*/
}
```

This works for my case.